# Power BI DAX - reuse measures in resultset

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

I am new with DAX and Power BI. I have a Power BI resultset with an unique identifier (ID), a column (REF_ID) that references to the ID column, but is nullable, and a measure (MSR). Now I simply want to make a calculation:
New_Measure = MSR (if REF_ID is NULL)
New_Measure = MSR + MSR_REF_ID (so the MSR from the ID that is referencing from REF_ID).

Example:
New_Measure(ID=3) = Measure(ID=3) + Measure(ID=6) = -5283619.953 + 1911594.57332966

Who can help???

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGAuW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new column in Power BI using below formula:

```
New_Measure = IF(Ref_ID = BLANK(), MSR, MSR + LOOKUPVALUE(MSR, ID, REF_ID))
```

You can refer syntax for [IF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/if-function-dax) and [LOOKUPVALUE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/lookupvalue-function-dax) for DAX

Comment: Great - exactly what I needed. Works as desired. Thank you so much

Comment: Good to know, thanks for confirming that it worked. Please accept it as the answer and upvote if this was what you were looking for.